# Accessing array when passed as an argument in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been using the following command to test the function:
`$hit sword 2 n`

I've been playing around with console logs and logging wpn within the damage function returns sword. but when trying to call from the sword array by logging wpn[1] it returns "w". I feel like there's a simple solution that I'm just not seeing here.

```
const PREFIX ='$';
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" "); //Reads discord comment with prefix $
let sword=[[4,6,6,6,6,8,10],["np"]];
let dam1=damage(args[2],args[1],args[3]);
message.channel.send("Your "+args[1]+" deals "+dam1+" damage.");
function damage(mod,wpn,armr){
    let dam=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + +mod;
    switch(wpn[1]){
        case "pierce":
            if (armr="y"){
                dam+=1;
            }
        break;
        case "np":
        break;
    }
    if(dam<0){
       dam=0;
    } else if(dam>6){
        dam=6;
    };
    return wpn[0][dam];
};
```

Comment: wpn = "sword", so wpn[1] = "w".

Comment: A string is not replaced with the value of a variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args[1]` is the string `"sword"`. That doesn't get replaced with the value of the `sword` variable.

If you want to use strings to access values, use an object to map them.

```
objects = {
    "sword": [[4,6,6,6,6,8,10],["np"]],
    ...
};

let dam1=damage(args[2],objects[args[1]],args[3]);
```